# What game does this black die belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

[image: Black Die]
[image: Rotated view]
[image: cropped view for google image search]

Bought a house and found this die in the backyard. The icon is in the spot where the 1 would go. This has peaked my curiosity and have tried to search google image but have had no luck. I also thought it looked like a boxer's glove. I have asked friends & family if they knew. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's possible its not from a game and maybe a promotional item?  I've had dice from conventions where the '1' was replaced by logo of event.  Its possible you might get dice with a logo made for promotional reasons?

Answer (score 5):

These dice are from the Pokèmon XY Furious Fists Elite Trainer Box.

source: https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/product-gallery/xy-furious-fists-elite-trainer-box/