# What game do these dice go to?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I remember that these dice went to a specific game that we played growing up. (I was born in '75.) But that is all I can remember!

[image]

Comment: Which face is replaced by the bug icon?

Comment: If the die is otherwise standard, it must be either 1 or 6, as 2 pairs with 5, and 3 with 4. 1 pairs with 6 and neither are visible.

Comment: The 1 is replaced.

Comment: You could ask dicecollector.com

Comment: The design is of course different, but could this be a similar situation to [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/what-game-does-this-black-die-belong-to), where there's speculation that the die isn't for a particular game but is some kind of promotional item?

Comment: I found a picture of the same dice on dicecollector.com. They are listed as unknown. ☹️ I also emailed them. ‍♀️

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dice appear to be from a game called [Don't Bug Me](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/43047/dont-bug-me), published in 1969/1970 by the Pacific Game Company (of California).
[image: Outer box of game]

A look inside the box reveals a pair of dice with an identical bug on each die:
[image: Box contents, showing dice, score card and betting chips]

(Note that many other companies have released unrelated games under the same name too.)

Comment: YES!!!!!! That’s it!!! I remember now!!!!! Oh my goodness!! Thank you!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

The picture of a bug on the dice made me think of the game [Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle_(game)) (also known as Beetle Drive). It's played by rolling a die, and drawing the relevant part of the beetle according to the number shown on the die. The first to complete their beetle drawing wins.

A comment below mentioned the game Cootie, which appears to be based upon the same idea, but using plastic parts to build a beetle. While the commenter recalls using a spinner, some editions included dice.

Here's one image from [BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1022849/cootie) that has a similar coloured die (but doesn't show the "bug" face:
[image]

Comment: I was thinking *Cootie* when I saw the dice, but then I recalled that game uses a spinner.

Comment: Beetle sounds familiar. When I look up the game, none of that is at all familiar though. ‍♀️ I do remember it being a game with these 2 dice as a set. I was the oldest of 6 kids, & like a number of other things, not everything survived.  Some how I managed to keep these as I tended to “acquisition” things like dice to keep them safe. (Collected, hoarded, or just keeping some things as mine, - I dunno.) I’ll keep googling. Thx for the ideas!!!

Comment: @JenniferHarding I wouldn't mark the answer as accepted if it's not actually correct... leaving it unaccepted can encourage more people to look at it; and maybe someone else will know. Also, you can try emailing the guy that runs www.dicecollector.com; he's helpful for things like this!

Comment: Thx. I was “Liking” it.  I think this is my first time having a public posted conversation like this. (Joint a forum I guess‍♀️) I fixed it!

Comment: I did email him, & I found an image on his site of the same dice. His photo is also of a set. But they are marked unknown. He emailed back that he has himself wondered for years.

Comment: That dice in the Cooties game is the same color!! ‍♀️

Comment: How do I add another photo? I took one showing all 6 sides between the 2 of them. (I started second guessing myself about which number was replaced since, dicecollector.com has a photo only of the bug side of both dice.) I’m using an iPhone to do this. I see no way to attach, or to paste it. 

Comment: @JenniferHarding you can edit your question (above) to add more photos, or additional text.

Comment: Thank you!! I’ll add the picture now just it’s there for any who have an interest. Even though, someone actually knew which game it was from.                  Hmmmmm... I tried to edit this & add the pic, but it’s just not working. Maybe it’s my phone?? ‍♀️